# I need help making this needle tube smooth

Tags: modeling, smooth

[image: needle in question]

ive been trying to model a needle but it came out looking sharply polygonal and i need it as a smooth tube

Comment: Hello have you right clicked and shade smoothed? If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i have subdivided and shade smoothed all i got was a nicer connection to the needle itself

Comment: please share your file

Comment: file has been shared

Comment: You need to copy paste the link it has generated ;)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Yoae1Nl9" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Yoae1Nl9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cylinder is subdivided but the subdivisions flatten the faces, you must have done a right click > *Subdivide* instead of applying a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, which didn't round the shape contrary to what you maybe expected:

[image]

to fix that you could select all and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* but it will be as fast to redo your cylinder from scratch with the wanted resolution.

Comment: thank you very much i will start working on it

Comment: @CreeptechArt, if this answer was useful, don't forget to upvote and eventually accept it !